# AngularJS $route service undesirable hash issue

Tags: angularjs, hash, routes

I'm working on a big project. This project already has complicated structure. Most pages are generated on server-side with Twig. 
 Now we move the project to AngularJS.
 It is not possible to use angular-way routing on whole project just now. But somewhere, it is necessary.

And here comes our trouble.

If I add 'ng-app' in html tag, for example, on some pages angular add hash in url.
 And what is strange for me, that it's not everywhere.
 On start page (project/profile9868766), url is clear as it is. But on some other (project/community/list), angular does something like that: project/community/list/#list .
And it is extremely undesirable.
 There are no any angular routes, configured in $route service yet.
 Please, help me to find out what causes that behavior, and what should i do to make all the things to go right way.

I want to add ng-app in html tag and not get any troubles with existing code, that may use hashes. And I want to use angular directives, controllers and other stuff, including $location service to set and track hashes on some pages. And later move everything to Angular and only after that start using Angular routes.

Thanks!

PS: English is not my native language, sorry about some weird constructions and mistakes. ))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn on html5mode

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

But the hash is inevitable on non-html5 browser.

Comment: Thanx, but it is almost the same in both modes. Switching mode just makes hash to look different. Angular is still changing url. A bit later i'll write, what it is exactly does.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of angular (v1.0.7) seems to have fixed this issue.

Comment: No^ we are using 1.2.x